# How do I filter nested objects using linq without foreach?

Tags: c#, linq, arraylist

I have a class "A" object with data. I need to filter based the below condition.

```
class A
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
    public Bool Status{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual List<B> AddressDetails { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public Guid AddressId { get; set;}
    public String Area{ get; set; }      
    public Bool AreaStatus{ get; set;}
}
```

Condition

```
Class a.Status=True and
Class b.AreaStatus= True
```

Note: Multiple Class "B" is assigned to single class "A". I need to return class A object with all class b mutiple data associated as areastatus true

How to filter data in class "A" object using linq instead of foreach and get the data.

Comment: Can you show your code where you want to filter this _class A_? I suppose that you have a List of these A objects. Then can you explain how should be considered an instance with _a.Status==true_ but with some elements (not all) in _AddressDetails.Status == false;_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you ?

```
list.Where(x =>x.Status).SelectMany(y=>y.AddressDetails.Where(z=>z.AreaStatus)).ToList();
```

Where list is collection of "A" and first filtering based on "A" status and then based on all the B objects whose AreaStatus is true

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, I'm assuming you have a `List<A>` and are looking for all entries of `AddressDetails` with `AreaStatus = true` where `Status` of the parent class `A` is also true:

```
List<A> _listA = [...] // your data
IEnumerable<B> filteredData = _listA.Where(x => x.Status)
                                    .SelectMany(x => x.AddressDetails)
                                    .Where(x => x.AreaStatus);
```

However, if you're trying to find all instances of `A` with at least one `AreaStatus = true`, this will do it:

```
IEnumerable<A> filteredData2 = _listA.Where(x => x.Status && 
                                                 x.AddressDetails.Any(y => y.AreaStatus));
```